# PHP-FPM setup under Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, unix

I'm trying to setup some kind of shared hosting environment under Ubuntu 16.04 using apache (and php7.0), but I can't manage to get it to work. After a bit of research I found that using php-fpm and fastcgi would be a great solution, as I need one php config for each user.

I installed these packages : `libapache2-mod-fastcgi php7.0-fpm php7.0`.   I added one user named "web", and set up permissions to his vhost folder using `usermod -d /var/www/web web`.
The vhost config looks like this (I need to be able to use it without domain, so here it listen on the port 81) :

```
Listen 81

<VirtualHost *:81>
ServerName example.org
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/web
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
  AddHandler php7-fcgi-web .php
  Action php7-fcgi-web /php7-fcgi-web virtual
  Alias /php7-fcgi-web /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-web
  FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7-fcgi-web -socket /var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.web.sock -pass-header Authorization
  <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</IfModule>
</VirtualHost>
```

I've also modified the following values in the pool file located at `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/web.conf`:

```
[web]
 ...
 user = web
 group = web
 ...
 listen = /run/php/php7.0-fpm.web.sock
 ...
 listen.owner = web
 listen.group = web
```

The problem is that when I try to load a .php web page, I get an "Internal Server Error" (while it works perfectly for html pages). Do you have any idea of what I could possibly be doing wrong, and if not, how could I try to debug php-fpm ? (I've already tried `apachectl -t` which returns no error, so it seems that apache works fine here).

Thanks for reading this post, and for your answers !

Comment: Apache by default runs under a different user `www-data` no matter who's initializing it  so you may need to check how you can get it to run under a specific user.

Comment: I don't believe it's the issue there, because apache works perfectly (it's only when i try to execute .php files that the problem appears), plus launching one apache process per user would be terrible for performance :/
I think it comes from a misconfiguration of php-fpm (which should do the job) but I can't figure out where

Comment: FPM would probably reject incoming requests from apache because those requests will be from user `www-data`, and it's listening for requests coming from user `web` is what I'm saying. If you want a per-user FPM then you need to set `listen.owner` and `listen.group` to `www-data` , you can keep the user and group as they are now. That way you'll have one pool per site all served by the same apache server/user.

Comment: It works now ! Thanks you so much :D